# How can I get my php hits from yesterday only?

Tags: php

How can I get my php hits from yesterday only when I am getting my total hits using this php sql call. Here is the code:

```
    SELECT *, COUNT(visitor_tracking.model_id) as model_count FROM user, visitor_tracking WHERE visitor_tracking.model_id = $user_id GROUP BY $user_id ORDER BY model_count DESC LIMIT 1
```

when the data day is being inserted this way. here is the code:

2013-12-11 14:23:45

and my database name is timestamp.

How can I get the php hits only from yesterday?

Comment: Convert all times to timestamps, create beginning and end timestamps and see which fall into the range

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2013-12-11 14:23:45)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `between`. For example, something like this should work:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(visitor_tracking.model_id) as model_count 
FROM user, visitor_tracking 
WHERE visitor_tracking.model_id = $user_id AND 
    `timestamp` BETWEEN '2013-12-11 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-11 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY $user_id ORDER BY model_count DESC LIMIT 1
```

BTW, I'm not sure you need the `DESC LIMIT 1` in that query because of the use of `COUNT`, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE created_time < 'yesterday date 00:00:00'
AND created_time > DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -1
DAY ) 
I hope it helps